# Statement won't execute because CPU execute simultaneously

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 2 classes: `static TimeManager` and `ball`, where `ball` is dependent on `TimeManager`.

**TimeManager.cs:**

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (isMoving) Timer();
    else
    {
        //isMoving = true;   //<- When I uncomment this, the problem occurs
    }

}

void Timer()
{
    currentTimeMove += Time.deltaTime * TimeDeductSpeed;

    if (currentTimeMove >= timeToMove)
    {
        isMoving = false;
        currentTimeMove = 0;
        perc = 0;
    }
    else perc = currentTimeMove / timeToMove;            
}
```

**Ball.cs:**

```
void FixedUpdate() => MovePerBlock();

void MovePerBlock()
{
    if (TimeManager.ins.isMoving)
        transform.localPosition = Vector3.Lerp(startPosition, endPosition, TimeManager.ins.perc);
    else //<- This statement does not execute when TimeManager.isMoving = true is uncommented
    {
        startPosition = transform.localPosition;
        endPosition = startPosition + transform.forward;
    }
}
```

The movement on each `ball` instance will depend on `TimeManager`.
They move and stop together. The script is working fine if I wait until they stop moving and set manually `isMoving` at the inspector even repeat the same action.

When I uncomment 'isMoving = true', the `else` statement in `ball.cs` doesn't always execute. I believe this because the execution times are fast.

Comment: 1. what is `timeToMove` (what value does it have)? 2. What exactly does "doesn't always execute" mean? what exactly is happening and how is it different from what you expect

Comment: `timeToMove` cant be anything, letsay 2 seconds, which mean it takes 2 second for ball to complete 1 move. 

the else statement in `ball` will only be execute if `isMoving` is false, but since we set `isMoving = true`, sometimes it does not execute else statement since the cpu set `isMoving` from `false` to `true` too fast.

Comment: You are still not really saying what you expect to happen. However your design seems to be flawed as you are modifying and accessing `isMoving` in `FixedUpdate` and I am not sure whether Unity makes any guarantees as for what order the scripts are called in. It is entirely possible that that order changes each time `FixedUpdate` gets called and this causes the behaviour you observe

Comment: what i expect is all the `ball` instances will move in 2 seconds and stop at the same time, and then those action is repeated, that's why I set `isMoving` to `true`. I put in FixedUpdate since i'm dealing with rigidbody movement. is there any other way to achieve this ? moving all instance simultaneously base on one TimeManager.

Comment: The one issue i see with your code is that you are relying on `TimeManager` `FixedUpdate` to execute before that of the ´ball´ instances. As I already said that is not guaranteed as Unity may execute them in an arbitrary order. There are several possibilities to work around this, though all of them require major changes to your code. You may probably require a custom startup and execution ordering to ensure that `isMoving` is not set to `true` too early.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your method kinda explain your problem.

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (isMoving) Timer();
    else // this is same as else if(isMoving == false)
    {
        //isMoving = true;   //<- When I uncomment this, the problem occurs
    }
}
```

The Timer method is called when isMoving is true. In Timer, you do some actions and at some point, Timer will set isMoving to false as the action is fully done.

But next frame, Timer method gets isMoving as false (else statement) and within the else statement, isMoving is set to true. So right next frame, you are doing the Timer action again.

As a result, only one frame is not doing the action. In the end, you seem to only see the items moving and never stopping.

The isMoving needs to be set via another condition than itself being false.

EDIT: As you describe the expected effect, I don't see why you are using this logic. It seems your ball is meant to always move, then I don't get why you need the reset. From what I see, you need to create a sawtooth wave.

```
public float amplitude = 2f;
public float period = 2f;

void Update(){
    float tOverP = Time.time / period;
    float result = (tOverP - Mathf.Floor(tOverP)) * amplitude;
    Debug.Log (result);
}
```

With this process you do not need to reset anything, you jump keep it going. The perc variable is the result variable.

Amplitude is how big you want the movement. With this setting, it goes from 0 to 2. The period variable defines how long to get from 0 to amplitude. So with this setting, from 0 to 2 in 2s.

Comment: actually I really want them to never stopping, that's why `isMoving` is set to `true` on else. the reason of Timer() is, to make sure that each ball moving in 2 second(or any time specified) and then stop and then repeat the same action. basically it works like this, ball moving from 0-5s, `if t > 5s`, t will be reset to 0, and ball will move again from 0-5s.

Comment: the reason for me to reset is to make sure the movement is in the grid base. means like all the ball moving per block even they lerp, they already move in grid if and only if `isMoving` is `commented` in `TimeManager` and I manually toggle `isMoving` after all the `ball` just stop. the problem only come when `isMoving` is `uncomment`.